# Software centre "Failed to download package"?

Tags: 11.10, software-center

I installed ubuntu 11.10 and started with the software center. At first no software had the install option so I chose "Use the source". But the download (whatever it was downloading...) was taking too long so I canceled them.

When I next moved onto the "Get software" page, the INSTALL buttons had somehow appeared in any softwares I searched for, but none of them installed on my system when I tried to do so. I keep getting this "Failed to download package. Check connection" error even when I am parally working on Firefox.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` Does that help?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Type `sudo apt-get update` in the terminal and wait until it finishes. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and tried both `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`. But I was getting some error while updating. Then I changed my server (System Settings -> System -> Software Sources -> Download From) and it worked. You may try this.